# Accumulate not giving correct sum of my vector

Tags: c++, vector, accumulate

I have this issue:

```
int nCab = 11;
int nCabCombo;
std::vector<int>counter(nCab);
for(int i = nCab; i > 0; i--)
{
    counter[i] = i-1;
    std::cout<<counter[i]<<std::endl;
}
nCabCombo = std::accumulate(counter.begin(),counter.end(),0);
std::cout<<nCabCombo<<std::endl;
```

The output is for nCabCombo is 45 when it should be 55, for some reason the accumulate function is not adding the 10 that is at index 11 of my counter vector. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here please? Thank you!

Comment: Because of `i=nCab` you try to access `vector` at index 11, when it's maximum index is 10, it's causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Why initializing in reverse order ? Note also there is `std::iota` to fill a range with increasing values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
counter[i] = i-1; //when i == 11, this is an off by one error
```

An array, and by extension a vector, has range from `[0, size)`. If it has `nCab` elements, the maximum index is only `nCab - 1`. You're storing the last element outside the bounds of the vector. You should change it to:

```
 counter[i - 1] = i-1;
```

The missing element would have been `10`. When `accumulate` runs, that is why your sum is off by `10`.

Comment: Lol. Oops, rookie mistake. I guess I just needed another set of eyes. Been coding for the past few hours and just missed that my vector indices were off in my loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You do not have an index 11.  You have 11 elements in you vector which means the valid indexes are `[0, 10]`.  `counter[i] = i-1;` is undefined behavior since you are accessing one past the end of the vector.

Ignoring the UB your vector actually contains `{0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` which is 45

Note: The reason it does not contain a `-1` is the for loop runs for `i > 0` so `i` will never be `0` and we will never set the first element of the vector so it remains `0` from the construction of the vector.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, you are accessing the element out of bounds.

However, instead of writing a loop and getting into this sort of trouble, you could use [std::iota](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int nCab = 11;
    std::vector<int>counter(nCab);
    std::iota(counter.begin(), counter.end(), 0);
    //...
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/uIUwcK)

---

If for some reason you really wanted to loop and populate the array in reverse (high index to low index), you could use [std::generate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) and use the reverse iterators:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int nCab = 11;
    std::vector<int>counter(nCab);
    int i = 11;
    std::generate(counter.rbegin(), counter.rend(), [&i] {return --i;});
    //...
}
```

[Live Example (std::generate)](http://ideone.com/IlxTlT)